# \texorpdfstring and Header setting

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters

I want to include chapters of the form

```
\chapter[Measures $\mu$]{\texorpdfstring{Measures $\boldsymbol{\mu}$}{Measures}}
```

Here the `[..]` are for formating the Layout in the title, and `\texorpdfstring{}{}` is used to distinguish between the heading and what is written in the toc.
When doing so, it ignores the pdf string and I get the correct heading, the correct header but the wrong output in the PDF heading.

Can someone tell me why and indicate a way to fix this?

Comment: the short form from the `[]` option is used in the toc and pdf so `\texorpdfstring` in the main argument is not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PDF bookmarks are a kind of table of contents, package `hyperref` catches the string for the table of contents, the optional argument of the sectioning commands, for the bookmarks. `\texorpdfstring` should go there.

`\textmu` is also available in the default PDFDocEncoding. To get a broader support for math symbols, option `unicode` (or `pdfencoding=auto`) and `psdextra` for additional support for lots of math symbol macros can be used.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter[Measures \texorpdfstring{$\mu$}{\textmu}]%
  {Measures $\boldsymbol{\mu}$}
\end{document}
```

I would try to avoid math in chapter/section titles though, because bold symbols often have a different meaning as non-bold symbols in math and a font mixup in the titles does not look too nice.