# automatic \texorpdfstring for \ref in pdf bookmarks (section titles)

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, header-footer, chapters, cleveref

```
\section{Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:main}}
```

doesn't produce the correct pdf bookmark (using the `hyperref` package).

```
\section{Proof of \texorpdfstring{Theorem~\ref{thm:main}}{Theorem 3.1.7}}
```

would give the wished result ([\texorpdfstring and Header setting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421845/texorpdfstring-and-header-setting)), but since "`3.1.7`" is hard coded I have to change this line of code every time when I rearrange my text.

I understand that many mathematical forumalas cannot be used as pdf strings (pdf bookmarks) since they don't have a Unicode representation ([Automatically add \texorpdfstring for math-mode in section titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306988/automatically-add-texorpdfstring-for-math-mode-in-section-titles)).

But "Theorem 3.1.7" only contains plain ASCII symbols. So at least theoretically it should be possible to implement an automatic solution for that.

Ideally I would like to have code that allows me to just write:

```
\section{Proof of \Cref{thm:main}}
```

(by using the `cleveref` package, but a solution for `\ref` would already be very helpful too)

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}\label{thm:main}
        text
    \end{theorem}

many pages

\section{Proof of \Cref{thm:main}}  
\end{document}
```

(this code does not give the correct pdf bookmarks)

<sub>(PS: I think this would be a really great to include such a code in the `hypperref` or in the `cleveref` package)</sub>

Comment: it would be much easier to answer if you would add a complete example ...

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik: Thank you very much! The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485979/128042 perfectly solves my problem (even though the questions are different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Phelype Oleinik linked to a very good solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485979/128042

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \let\Cref\crtCref
    \let\cref\crtcref
}
\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}\label{thm:main}
        text
    \end{theorem}

many pages

\section{Proof of \Cref{thm:main}}  
\end{document}
```

This solution to the different question [Hide cleveref links in section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485976/hide-cleveref-links-in-section-title) answers this question also perfectly.

Ulrike Fischer solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504969/128042 is a great alternative if you cannot use the `crossreftools` package.

Comment: well it is not a perfect solution as it patches a hyperref command. But you don't need \hypersetup related part for your problem.

Comment: Yes removing the `hypersetup` part improves the solution, so I removed it. I think both solutions have advantages. This solutions for example keeps the colors and allows the use of `\Cref`. Your solution is simpler and less invasive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the starred version of \ref:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Proof of Theorem~\texorpdfstring{\ref{thm:main}}{\ref*{thm:main}}}
\begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:main} some theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```