# Putting Cross-references in the PDF Outline

Tags: sectioning, pdftex, cross-referencing

Sometimes when writing maths documents, I want to have the name of a theorem in a section heading. This works fine in the text of the document, but it runs into trouble in the PDF outline. Specifically, the name of the section in the outline contains the *label* of the theorem, rather than its actual printed number in the text. How can I get around this?

In the MWE below, the offending section heading will print as "Proof of Theorem 1.1" in the text, but as "Proof of thmName" in the outline. I want it to also say "Proof of Theorem 1.1" in the outline.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

In this paper we prove the following result, which requires a bunch of lemmas to be given first.

\begin{thm}\label{thmName}
    Some result.
\end{thm}

\section{Required Results}

Here we give a bunch of lemmas.

\section{Proof of \cref{thmName}} % The offending section heading

We draw the lemmas together into a proof of \cref{thmName}.

\end{document}
```

I compile this with PDFLaTeX, and it seems this is a problem with `hyperref`. The warning I get from it is

```
Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\new@ifnextchar' on input line 22
```

---

### Update

By following Jakob's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504968/automatic-texorpdfstring-for-ref-in-pdf-bookmarks-section-titles), I've been able to get this working as follows:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % Note that the environment is now named 'theorem' rather than 'thm'.
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \let\Cref\crtCref
    \let\cref\crtcref
}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

In this paper we prove the following result, which requires a bunch of lemmas to be given first.

\begin{theorem}\label{thmName}
    Some result.
\end{theorem}

\section{Required Results}

Here we give a bunch of lemmas.

\section{Proof of \cref{thmName}}

We draw the lemmas together into a proof of \cref{thmName}.

\end{document}
```

However, it absolutely requires me to name the theorem environment 'theorem' rather than 'thm'. If I do the above with `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` instead, all sorts of errors are thrown. Why would this be?

Comment: Almost. The problem with this solution is that I lose the convenience of cleveref in the section headings. If I change the 'Theorem' to a 'Lemma', say, then I have to manually go to all the relevant section headings and change the work 'Theorem' to 'Lemma'.

Comment: you can't use \cref, but you could create a lightweight expandable version with the zref package.

Comment: The later solution by Jakob also doesn't work for me either, even if I change the document class to 'article'.

Comment: The documentation for zref is completely opaque to me.

Comment: well then do something like `\newcommand\mythmref[1]{Theorem~\ref{#1}}
` in the preamble and then use `\mythmref{thmName}`.